# How can I pass parameters to django api call via redux?

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

How can I pass the `name, age, height` arguments to my redux action ?
I am using django rest api as the backend

```
export const Search_Results = (name, age, height) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/")
            .then(res => {
                const info = res.data;
                dispatch(presentResult(info))
            });
    }
};
```

The presentResult is

```
export const presentResult = results => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.PRESENT_RESULTS,
        results: results
    }
};
```

My reducer is

```
const presentResult = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        results: action.results
    });
};



switch (action.type)
        case actionTypes.PRESENT_RESULTS:
            return presentResult(state, action);
```

The updateObject is simply this

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject, 
        ...updatedProperties
    }
};
```

**Update:**

Basically `info` is all the data in the database, and the user searches by passing the parameters `name, age, height`. I am trying to filter the `info` data and to pass it only if it has any of the keywords in `name, age, height`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make them part of the payload:

```
 dispatch(presentResult({info, name, age, height}));
```

You'll be able to access the values in reducer like so:

```
//...
case actionTypes.PRESENT_RESULTS,:
  return {...state, results: action.results} 

//...
```

Edit: If you want to actually filter the data in reducer, use `filter` method for arrays:

```
//...
case actionTypes.PRESENT_RESULTS,:
  return {
    ...state,
    results: state.results.filter(result => {
      return result.name === action.results.name || result.age === action.results.age || result.height === action.results.height
    })
  }

//...

If you want to find an object by exact match on all the fields, use `&&` instead.
```

Comment: What's the initialState look like?

Comment: Updated the answer. In this case you don't need to use updateObject, since all you want to do is add a new object to an array.

Comment: thanks for that but I think it doesn't fix the issue. Basically `info` is all the data in the database, and the user searches by passing the parameters `name, age, height`. I am trying to filter the `info` data and pass it only if it has any of the keywords in `name, age, height`.

Comment: Ok, I guess you need to change your question then. What you're trying to do is to pass the params to django api call, not to redux action.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for that. But, is it possible to filter the results from the `info` using `name, age, height` in the reducers instead ?

Comment: Why would you need to filter the results on the state if you're making an api call? Shouldn't that do the filtering? The api returns filtered results and then you just save them to the store.

Comment: in theory yes. But I was exploring an alternative solution, where all data comes from `info`, and the reducer actually does the filtering in accordance to `name, age, height`

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good approach, since in that case you'll need to have all the results available in the store in order to filter them. Anyway, I've updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: I have now modified the backend to receive "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?name=xyz" how can I modify the redux action to pass that to the django api?

Comment: Just pass it as a query param: `axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", {
  params: {
    name: 'xyz'
  }})`